# Cant read sqlite database in listview android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, android-fragments

Activity type is "fixed tabs + swipe". I need read data from DB sqlite in my Listvew, which located in fragment xml file (not in main xml). L use my old code from some program, there is a method for creating listview:

```
public void createList(){
    db = new DB(this);
    db.open();
    String[] from = new String[] {DB.COLUMN_NAME, DB.COLUMN_TIME  };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.tvTextName, R.id.tvText_time};
    scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, null, from, to, 0);
    lvData = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvData);
    lvData.setAdapter(scAdapter);
    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
}
```

In simple activity code works ok, but i don't know how to use that code in fragment activity. I try call that method in main class but that code:

```
lvData = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvData);
    lvData.setAdapter(scAdapter);
```

i put in fragment class. Program working, but list view is empty. DB is not empty. There is main parts of code:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
ActionBar.TabListener, LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {


    //*****ОСНОВНЫЕ ПЕРЕМЕННЫЕ*****

    private static String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private static final int CM_DELETE_ID = 1;
    private static final int RESET_STOPWATCH = 2;
    static ListView lvData;
    static DB db;
    static SimpleCursorAdapter scAdapter;
    static Context ctx;
    static String[] from = new String[] {DB.COLUMN_NAME, DB.COLUMN_TIME  };
    static int[] to = new int[] { R.id.tvTextName, R.id.tvText_time};

    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager
        .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                    .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }
        ctx = this;
        createList();
    }

    public void createList(){
        db = new DB(this);
        db.open();
        scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, null, from, to, 0);Log.d(TAG, "1");
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
        // the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
            // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
            if(position == 0){  
                Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
                fragment.setArguments(args);
                //getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
                return fragment;
            }

            if (position == 1)
            {
                Fragment fragment2 = new DummySectionFragment2();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt(DummySectionFragment2.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 2);
                fragment2.setArguments(args);
                return fragment2;
            }
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
    public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment{
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
        public DummySectionFragment() {
        }

        static View v;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tracker,
                    container, false);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tracker, container, false);
            lvData = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lvData);Log.d(TAG, "2");
            lvData.setAdapter(scAdapter);Log.d(TAG, "3");
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    public static class DummySectionFragment2 extends Fragment {
            //code page 2
        }
    }

    //Класс по управлению БД
    static class MyCursorLoader extends CursorLoader {

        DB db;

        public MyCursorLoader(Context context, DB db) {
            super(context);
            this.db = db;
        }

        @Override
        public Cursor loadInBackground() {
            Cursor cursor = db.getAllData();
            return cursor;
        }

    }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have setup a similar application reading database details into a fragment containing a ListView. I have done this through JSON parsing.

Take a look at the following:

```
public static class EventFragment extends ListFragment {

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> eventsList;
        private String url_all_events = "//url of the location of your database";

        //used a Progressbar to prompt the user that the data is downloading until it downloads.
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // JSON Node names
        private static final String CONNECTION_STATUS = "success";
        private static final String TABLE_EVENT = "Event";
        private static final String pid = "pid";
        private static final String COL_GROUP = "Group";
        private static final String COL_NAME = "Event_Name";
        private static final String COL_DESC = "Event_Desc";
        private static final String COL_DATE = "Event_Date";
        private static final String COL_TIME = "Event_Time";

        JSONArray Events = null;

        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public EventFragment() {
        }

        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();

            eventsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            new LoadAllEvents().execute();

            // selecting single ListView item
            ListView lv = getListView();

            // Lauching the Event details screen on selecting a single event
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // getting values from selected ListItem
                    String ID = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid))
                            .getText().toString();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),
                            EventDetails.class);
                    intent.putExtra(pid, ID);
                    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_events,
                    container, false);

            return rootView;
        }

        class LoadAllEvents extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            /**
             * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
             * */
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                pDialog.setMessage("Just a moment...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();
            }

            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                // getting JSON string from URL
                JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_events,
                        "GET", params);

                try {
                    // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                    int success = json.getInt(CONNECTION_STATUS);

                    if (success == 1) {
                        // products found
                        // Getting Array of Products
                        Events = json.getJSONArray(TABLE_EVENT);
                        // looping through All Contacts
                        for (int i = 0; i < Events.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject evt = Events.getJSONObject(i);

                            // Storing each json item in variable
                            id = evt.getString(pid);
                            group = evt.getString(COL_GROUP);
                            name = evt.getString(COL_NAME);
                            desc = evt.getString(COL_DESC);
                            date = evt.getString(COL_DATE);
                            time = evt.getString(COL_TIME);

                            // creating new HashMap
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                            map.put(pid, id);
                            map.put(COL_GROUP, group);
                            map.put(COL_NAME, name);
                            map.put(COL_DESC, desc);
                            map.put(COL_DATE, date);
                            map.put(COL_TIME, time);

                            // adding HashList to ArrayList
                            eventsList.add(map);
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Options are not available or server is down.
                        // Dismiss the loading dialog and display an alert
                        // onPostExecute
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
                pDialog.dismiss();
                // updating UI from Background Thread
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(),
                                eventsList, R.layout.list_item, new String[] {
                                        pid, COL_GROUP, COL_NAME, COL_DATE, COL_TIME },
                                new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.group, R.id.name, R.id.header,
                                        R.id.title2 });

                        setListAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                });

            }

        }
    }
```

For the JSON Parser, I used the following class:

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if (method == "POST") {
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            } else if (method == "GET") {
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

And finally, this is the xml file for the fragment layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"> 
    <!-- Main ListView  
         Always give id value as list(@android:id/list) 
    -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Here I have used a Custom Listview so please note that the way I implemented it, may be a little bit complicated.

Hope this helps :)